# OSX Run Bash or App as the screensaver

Tags: macos, screensaver

Is it possible to use an Application or bash script as the screensaver?

I would to like to run a bash script [pmatrix](https://github.com/prggmr/matrix) or App (iTerm) as the screensaver?

I'm on 10.6.8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, that program should do what you want – at least start a normal application:

> #### [AppStartSaver](http://www.themcdonalds.net/richard/index.php?title=AppStartSaver)
>
> This is a simple screen saver for Mac OS X version 1.3+ that launches a regular Mac application, or a Unix executable, of your choice when the screen saver starts.
>
> [image]

Comment: Excellent little App.. use it with in combination with "Purge" to "reclaim" some memory in Lion (it tends to eat a lot and I go really low in memory some times) when my computer goes to screen-saver (and I am not actively using it - this is nice because it always takes 10/15 seconds to execute purge).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to *slhck*'s answer, you can use [**ScriptSaver**](https://swannman.github.io/scriptsaver/), since, if you have `Require password after sleep or screen saver begins` enabled after IIRC OS X `10.7` you'll otherwise not see through and get a black screen (I'm on `10.8.5`). Here's an example of using it to launch `iTerm` with `top`.

[image: ScriptSaver Settings]

**Activation Script**

`tell application "iTerm" to create window with profile "Hotkey Window" command "top"`

**Screen Saver**

[LookThrough](https://github.com/qvacua/lookthrough). Alternatively, [JohnnyNash](https://github.com/marczak/johnnynash), [Transparent](https://www.monkeybreadsoftware.de/Software/Transparent.shtml).

**Deactivation Script**

```
tell application "iTerm"
close front window
quit
end tell
```